# How to load an image sequence into a shader to be sampled independently?

Tags: shader, directx, hlsl

I am trying to load a video (in the form of on-disk frames), in a way that would allow to sample them independently (i.e. not one frame at a time, but sample any pixel of any frame at any time) in a fragment shader (either GLSL or HLSL).

The instruction I want to call per-fragment is akin to this pseudo-code:

```c
// we load 128 frames of images, and provide it to this function in some way, here it's called "video"
float4 fragmentShader(float2 fragmentUV, texture2D[128] video) {
    int frameToUse = rand(128); /* some calculation which gives a number in the 0-127 range, doesn't matter which one, so let's say random */
    float4 output_color = video[frameToUse].getValueAt(fragmentUV.x, fragmentUV.y);
    return output_color;
}
```

What is the correct way to load the images from disk to create (what is essentially a 3D color buffer called) `video` in that code?

My research has pointed to the seemingly-appropriately named [`sampler3D` and `sampler2DArray` types](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)) in GLSL and the [`Texture3D`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-texture3d) and [`Texture2DArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-texture2darray) types in HLSL, but have not found a straightforward example of loading on-disk images into one, and I'm not sure they're actually used for such a purpose.

Comment: Why do you repeat the question? [How to load image array (video frames) into shader to be independently sampled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76938941/how-to-load-image-array-video-frames-into-shader-to-be-independently-sampled). If you want to improve a question, you must edit the original question, but not create a new question.

Comment: @Rabbid76 If you read carefully, you will see a difference. The first one had two questions, how to load files, and how to sample the resulting buffer. It might seem like too much to ask in one place, so this question is only about loading the files.

Comment: I can see that. You have clarified and narrowed down your question. Then why did you not edit the first question, but deleted it and created a new one?

Comment: Because I first deleted the question entirely, and then decided to ask just the first part separately.

Comment: When it comes to OpenGL, i could recommend to study this: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures (loading single images from disk included).

Comment: Thank you @ErdalKüçük! This is a helpful overall article, and it mentions sampler3D in passing, but I still don't understand how to create one from an image array. In general, everything in shader programming seems to be incredibly verbose, but also incredibly specific, and I haven't found any info on how to handle video material in them.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük In the first place, I haven't been able to find the texture number limit for an OpenGL shader. Seems like it's the same as a sampler limit, but in HLSL/CG they're different types of objects with different limits, so I'm not sure if that's actually the case.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture) article first, then follow up with [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture), and keep [this](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage3D.xhtml) or [this](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/) always open. After or before, have also a look at [this](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) (Chapter 8 - Textures and Samplers).

Comment: Btw. the parameter `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` gives you the limitation for texture sizes, and `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS` the number of array levels (2048 on OpenGL 4.5).

Comment: When it comes to 'video material', well decoding a video stream results in single frames with certain timestamps (representation time). It depends on you how and when to upload the single frames onto the GPU. Decode a bunch of packets into frames (any media lib of your choice, OpenGL can't do that) then upload and process the frames in any specific format, type, etc. that OpenGL supports, be it as single 2D image textures or an array of those. If you followed the links i gave you, that shouldn't be any problem at this point.

Comment: Thank you for some pointers, @ErdalKüçük. The decoding into frames is already done, as the video is saved as separate image files per frame. However, the "upload and process the frames" part I still cannot figure out, hence the question. Since shader programming is quite a steep learning curve, I am struggling to understand what the correct "format, type, etc." needs to be specified and at which stage, as well as the best type to use (i.e. sampler2DArray or sampler3D), and what the practical differences between them even are.

Comment: Why do you need an array? What's the purpose? In your opinion, what benefit do you expect it to have?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük I need to be able to sample all the frames at once. To take parts of frame 0, parts of frame 1, parts of frame 2, depending on the UV coordinates (i.e. certain ranges of U coords are corresponding to certain frames). Because of this, I assume for real-time performance I need to load all the frames into the VRAM. But again, since I am new to shader programming, I might be wrong.

Comment: Well in this case, you'll have to create a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` (`glTexImage3D`). The max dimensions can be retrieved via `glGet` (params `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` and `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS`). Currently the minimum values are 1024 x 1024 x 2048 (on my system these values are 16384x16384x2048 - that means 2048 16k 2D images packed into one single texture as array). Bind that texture to a `sampler2DArray` and in the shader access the texels via `texture(u_tex, vec3(u, v, w));`, where the `w` argument describes the layer offset (array index).